# How can I create multiple prepared statements from one mysql::Conn?

Tags: mysql, rust

This code

```
extern crate mysql;
use mysql::*;

fn main () {
    let mut conn = Conn::new("mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?prefer_socket=false").unwrap();
    let _q1 = conn.prepare("some query").unwrap();
    let _q2 = conn.prepare("some query 2").unwrap();
}
```

produces the error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow ``conn`` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src\bin\test.rs:8:12
  |
7 |  let _q1 = conn.prepare("some query").unwrap();
  |            ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
8 |  let _q2 = conn.prepare("some query 2").unwrap();
  |            ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
9 | }
  | - first borrow ends here
```

I suppose that the first borrow lives up to the line 9 because `conn.prepare(...).unwrap()`'s  result is `Stmt` and `Stmt` is declared as

```
pub struct Stmt<'a> {
    stmt: InnerStmt,
    conn: ConnRef<'a>,
}
```

and `ConnRef` is declared as

```
enum ConnRef<'a> {
    ViaConnRef(&'a mut Conn), // It keeps mutable borrow as long as lifetime of connection?
    ViaPooledConn(pool::PooledConn),
}
```

so `_q1` keeps the mutable borrow until `conn` dies.

How can I create multiple prepared statements without producing compile-time error?

Comment: It rather looks like you *cannot*.

Comment: Thank you.
Is it intended behavior of crate or it is a bug? `Conn` looks too useless with this limitation. I have to use either Conn::query (without preparing statement) or pooled connection.

Comment: I don't actually know if it's on purpose or not. It's fairly surprising, so I'd tend to believe that I'm just missing something. However, I'd think that a pooled connection would be a better choice in most cases anyway...

Comment: If I create pooled connection as `let conn = Pool::new_manual(1, 1, "some_conn_string").unwrap();` then I can't create 2 prepared statements: 1st statement is prepared but the program freezes when preparing 2nd one. Similarly, if I create connection as `let conn = Pool::new_manual(1, 2, "conn_string").unwrap();` then I can create only 2 statements and get the hang on 3rd one. I guess each connection in the pool can keep only one prepared statement. Now note that `Pool::new` method (I think most people use it) creates new pool with min = 10 and max = 100 so we can never prepare 101+ statements.

Comment: I see no way (on protocol level) to execute multiple statements, prepared on the same connection, in parallel. And so i can't see practical benefits in having multiple prepared statements out of single `Conn` but this will definitely complicate things.
Each statement, once prepared, goes to `Conn`'s local cache which is fast enough (this is, in fact, "creating multiple prepared statements without producing compile-time error").
If your only `Conn` is in `lazy_static!` and you want to prepare 100+ statements on it, then just tweak `stmt_cache_size` accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/mysql/12.3.1/mysql/struct.Conn.html#method.prepare) does state:

> Stmt will borrow Conn until the end of its scope.

There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/blackbeam/rust-mysql-simple/issues/57) that suggests using [prep_exec](https://docs.rs/mysql/12.3.1/mysql/struct.Conn.html#method.prep_exec), claiming:

> Overhead is negligible because of fast xxhash based statements cache.